# Reset function is not working for JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming, and I am creating a psychic game where you guess the letter the computer created.

For some reason, when you select the letter the computer chose, the `reset();` function is not causing the guesses to reset, and still uses the previous computer guess as the letter, even though the `reset();` function creates a new computer guess. I've Googled this and haven't been able to find anything to answer my question. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Psychic Game</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="container">
                <h1>The Psychic Game</h1>

                <p><span id=main-text>Guess what letter I'm thinking of?</span></p>

                <P>Wins: <span id="wins">0</span> </P>

                <P>Losses: <span id="losses">0</span></P>

                <p>Guesses left: <span id="guessesLeft">10</span></p>

                <p>Your guesses so far:<span id="guessedLetters"> </span></p>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavScript:

```js
    var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
    "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    var guessesLeft = 10;
    var guessedLetters = [];


    //generate random letter

    var randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
    var computerChoice = alphabet[randomLetter];
    console.log("The computer choose " + computerChoice);

    //reset function
    function reset(){
        guessesLeft = 10;
        guessedLetters = [];
        var randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
        var computerChoice = alphabet[randomLetter];
        console.log("The computer choose " + computerChoice);
    }

    //event listener for keyup event
    document.onkeyup = function(event){
        //user makes choice
        var userChoice = event.key;
        //double check userChoice is viable
        var viableChoice = /[a-z]/gi;
        if (!viableChoice.test(userChoice)) {
        alert("please enter a letter");
        }
        else {
        console.log(userChoice);
        }
        //if user guesses the right letter
        if(userChoice !== computerChoice){
            guessesLeft--;
            document.getElementById("guessesLeft").innerText = guessesLeft;
            document.getElementById("main-text").innerText = "Try again!";
            guessedLetters.push(userChoice);
            document.getElementById("guessedLetters").innerText = guessedLetters;
        } else if(userChoice === computerChoice){
            wins++;
            alert("You won!");
            document.getElementById("wins").innerText = wins;
            reset();
        }
        if(guessesLeft === 0){
            losses++;
            document.getElementById("main-text").innerText = "You lose! Try again";
          reset();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never call reset.

Comment: `var randomLetter` and `var computerChoice` does not replace the global.

Comment: You didn't call your function

Comment: As epascarello notes, within `reset()` you're instantiating (unused) variables instead of setting the global ones.

Comment: How many people can say that it is not called.... Do people not look at comments before the comment?

Comment: I deleted reset(); from the if else statements because it wasn't working, but even if it is in there it does not work :(

Comment: @vivgarcia can you place it back in the else statements so we can see where it was meant to be called?

Comment: @vivgarcia See epascarello's comment. You're resetting local variables, not the global variables.

Comment: @epascarello `checkPreviousComments()` was never called.

Comment: @Jawi I updated it as requested!

Comment: just delete the `var`.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `reset()` function,

```
var randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
        var computerChoice = alphabet[randomLetter];
```

should be

```
randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
        computerChoice = alphabet[randomLetter];
```

You are defining new local vars when you just want to update the old ones.

Comment: Your answer is correct and can be improved upon by specifying which "var"s to remove. In this case, the ones within the reset function